# Android Gallery Auto Load

Tags: android, gallery, autoload

wondering if anyone can help change this code so it auto-loads instead of having to hit the search button? I would like to just call the activity and have it load the Flickr photos...right now i have to hit the Search button to load...thanks so much!

```
package com.windmillagency;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Gallery;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AndroidFlickrActivity extends Activity {

    public String thisActivityName = "Flickr";

    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    BackgroundThread backgroundThread;

    public class FlickrImage {
        String Id;
        String Owner;
        String Secret;
        String Server;
        String Farm;
        String Title;

        Bitmap FlickrBitmap;

        FlickrImage(String _Id, String _Owner, String _Secret, 
                String _Server, String _Farm, String _Title){
            Id = _Id;
            Owner = _Owner;
            Secret = _Secret;
            Server = _Server;
            Farm = _Farm;
            Title = _Title;

            FlickrBitmap = preloadBitmap();
        }

        private Bitmap preloadBitmap(){
            Bitmap bm= null;

            String FlickrPhotoPath = 
                    "http://farm" + Farm + ".static.flickr.com/" 
                    + Server + "/" + Id + "_" + Secret + "_m.jpg";

            URL FlickrPhotoUrl = null;

            try {
                FlickrPhotoUrl = new URL(FlickrPhotoPath);

                HttpURLConnection httpConnection 
                    = (HttpURLConnection) FlickrPhotoUrl.openConnection();
                httpConnection.setDoInput(true);
                httpConnection.connect();
                InputStream inputStream = httpConnection.getInputStream();
                bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return bm;
        }

        public Bitmap getBitmap(){
            return FlickrBitmap;
        }

    }

    class FlickrAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
        private Context context;
        private FlickrImage[] FlickrAdapterImage;;

        FlickrAdapter(Context c, FlickrImage[] fImage){
            context = c;
            FlickrAdapterImage = fImage;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return FlickrAdapterImage.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return FlickrAdapterImage[position];
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ImageView image;  
            if (convertView == null) {
                image = new ImageView(context);  
                image.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));  
                image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);  
                image.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);   
            } else {  
                image = (ImageView) convertView;    
            }  

            image.setImageBitmap(FlickrAdapterImage[position].getBitmap());

            return image; 
        }

    }

    FlickrImage[] myFlickrImage;

    /*
     * FlickrQuery = FlickrQuery_url 
     * + FlickrQuery_per_page 
     * + FlickrQuery_nojsoncallback 
     * + FlickrQuery_format
     * + FlickrQuery_tag + q
     * + FlickrQuery_key + FlickrApiKey
     */

    String FlickrQuery_url = "http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.people.getPublicPhotos&api_key=fdd73dc07613841fbe325b5103d673b7&user_id=65005067@N08&per_page=25&format=json";
    String FlickrQuery_per_page = "&per_page=10";
    String FlickrQuery_nojsoncallback = "&nojsoncallback=1";
    String FlickrQuery_format = "&format=json";
    String FlickrQuery_tag = "&tags=";
    String FlickrQuery_key = "&api_key=";

    //  Apply your Flickr API:
    //  www.flickr.com/services/apps/create/apply/?
    String FlickrApiKey = "fdd73dc07613841fbe325b5103d673b7";

    //final String DEFAULT_SEARCH = "Bill_Gate";
    final String DEFAULT_SEARCH = "new_york";

    EditText searchText;
    Button searchButton;

    Gallery photoBar;

    Bitmap bmFlickr;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        searchText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.searchtext);
        searchText.setText(DEFAULT_SEARCH);
        searchButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.searchbutton);

        photoBar = (Gallery)findViewById(R.id.photobar);

        searchButton.setOnClickListener(searchButtonOnClickListener);
    }

    private Button.OnClickListener searchButtonOnClickListener
    = new Button.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(AndroidFlickrActivity.this, 
                    "ProgressDialog", "Wait!");

            backgroundThread = new BackgroundThread();
            backgroundThread.setRunning(true);
            backgroundThread.start();




        }};


    private String QueryFlickr(String q){

        String qResult = null;

        String qString = 
                FlickrQuery_url 
                + FlickrQuery_per_page 
                + FlickrQuery_nojsoncallback 
                + FlickrQuery_format 
                + FlickrQuery_tag + q  
                + FlickrQuery_key + FlickrApiKey;

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(qString);

        try {
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpClient.execute(httpGet).getEntity();

            if (httpEntity != null){
                InputStream inputStream = httpEntity.getContent();
                Reader in = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(in);
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                String stringReadLine = null;

                while ((stringReadLine = bufferedreader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(stringReadLine + "\n");
                    }

                qResult = stringBuilder.toString();
                inputStream.close();
            }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return qResult;
    }

    private FlickrImage[] ParseJSON(String json){

        FlickrImage[] flickrImage = null;

        bmFlickr = null;
        String flickrId;
        String flickrOwner;
        String flickrSecret;
        String flickrServer;
        String flickrFarm;
        String flickrTitle;

        try {
            JSONObject JsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
            JSONObject Json_photos = JsonObject.getJSONObject("photos");
            JSONArray JsonArray_photo = Json_photos.getJSONArray("photo");

            flickrImage = new FlickrImage[JsonArray_photo.length()];
            for (int i = 0; i < JsonArray_photo.length(); i++){
                JSONObject FlickrPhoto = JsonArray_photo.getJSONObject(i);
                flickrId = FlickrPhoto.getString("id");
                flickrOwner = FlickrPhoto.getString("owner");
                flickrSecret = FlickrPhoto.getString("secret");
                flickrServer = FlickrPhoto.getString("server");
                flickrFarm = FlickrPhoto.getString("farm");
                flickrTitle = FlickrPhoto.getString("title");
                flickrImage[i] = new FlickrImage(flickrId, flickrOwner, flickrSecret,
                        flickrServer, flickrFarm, flickrTitle);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return flickrImage;
    }

    public class BackgroundThread extends Thread{
        volatile boolean running = false;
        int cnt;

        void setRunning(boolean b){
            running = b;    
            cnt = 10;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String searchQ = searchText.getText().toString();
            String searchResult = QueryFlickr(searchQ);

            myFlickrImage = ParseJSON(searchResult);


            handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage());
        }
    }

    Handler handler = new Handler(){

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            progressDialog.dismiss();
            photoBar.setAdapter(new FlickrAdapter(AndroidFlickrActivity.this, myFlickrImage));
            Toast.makeText(AndroidFlickrActivity.this, 
                    "Flickr images loaded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    };

}







XML File

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/searchtext"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/searchbutton"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Search"
    />
<TextView  
    android:id="@+id/queryresult"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    />
<Gallery  
    android:id="@+id/photobar"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
    android:spacing="10dp"  
    />  
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

From the main thread, you will want to call Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(). Use a handler to post to the main thread.

```
BaseAdapter mBaseAdapter;

// ... some init stuff 

mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
    @Override public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        mBaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        mHandler.sendEmptyDelayedMessage(-1, 100);
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Wonder if u could show me in the code how to implement...very new to this but I do have it working in the Emulator now :) thanks soo much if you could show me exactly where in the code to change things..I don't want the button there at all just load the Activity when it's called..thanks again!

Comment: You instantiate the handler in the constructor (with class scope) and then when ever you want to start the auto updater, just call `mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(-1);`

Comment: Thanks, I will try and research, i am very new to programming and just trying to modify the code...If you have the time to show me in my code that would be great! So much to learn..fun tho, thanks again!

Comment: Hi Again, I am reading/studying about Handlers and having trouble understanding how it would make this activity load the images without hitting the Load/refresh Button? Thanks for your time :)

Comment: The Handler I have shown you will reset its self every time it calls itself. The send empty message delayed send a message to itself in 100 ms. The will once again cause the adapter to update its content.